# NSPredicate 'Operator 'LIKE' not supported for type int'

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have a problem with NSPredicate format in Swift, I want to create a predicate that compares an Int value, functioning like "contains" or "LIKE" in String value.

Example :

- 1
- 12
- 31
- 511

If I type 1, then all numbers will be returned to predicate.

This is my line code looks like :

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id LIKE %d OR customerName contains %@", searchText, searchText)
```

I also had tried :

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id contains %d OR customerName contains %@", searchText, searchText)
```

But both above gave me error : 
'Operator 'LIKE' not supported for type int' and 'Operator 'contains' not supported for type int'

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would need to convert your customer numbers to strings

Comment: @Paulw11: Do you mean convert "id" to String inside NSPredicate?

Comment: No, you would need to store your id as a string in your database. You can only use LIKE on strings

Comment: Is this for Core Data, or why do you need a NSPredicate? Can't you store the numbers as strings?

Answer (score 0):

For int values you can directly use "==" operator and no need of LIKE operator, you can use the following predicate format,

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d OR customerName contains %@", searchText, searchText)
```

And if your using NSNumber then make sure that you get the actual value using the predefined methods, like intValue,

Comment: "==" operator will compare "id" with "exact" value instead of "contains" value

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id LIKE %d OR customerName contains %@", String(format: "%@",searchText), String(format: "%@",searchText))
```

Comment: It still gives the same error : 'Operator 'LIKE' not supported for type int'